# Angular test NavigationError event handler

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

I have a method that handles chunk load error and shows a notification. The problem is that I cannot mock `NavigationError` which I need in order to pass filter condition `filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationError && e.error.name === 'ChunkLoadError')`.

However, I cannot create this error on my own. When I create my instance of NavigationError I get error that

> Error: ASSERTION ERROR: NgModule 'NavigationError(id: 1, url: '1', error: 1)' is not a subtype of 'NgModuleType'. [Expected=> null != null <=Actual]

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
{
   path: 'loadErr',
   loadChildren: () =>Promise.resolve(new NavigationError(1, '1', 1)),
},
]),
```

How do I create an instace of this error?

Comment: instead of promise.resolve shouldn't you call promise.reject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't need to create `NavigationError` explicitly. You can reject the promise what will automatically cause `NavigationError`.

Now the route setup looks like this

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
  {
    path: 'loadErr',
    loadChildren: () =>
      Promise.reject({name: 'ChunkLoadError'}),
  },
]),
```

And the test itself

```
ngZone
  .run(() => router.navigateByUrl('loadErr'))
  .then(() => done.fail('Eror expected'))
  .catch(() => expect(notificationService.showError).toHaveBeenCalled());

  tick(100);
```